# Pass by value to closure

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, closures

Say we have the following case:

```
list names = ['foo','bar','derp','herp']
def outer_func():
   funcs = []
   for name in names:
      def inner_func():
         print(name)
      funcs.append(inner_func)
   return funcs

result_funcs = outer_func()
result_funcs[0]() # this will print 'herp'
```

I have debugged a bit and found that the closure holds a reference to name
so i tried doing this:

```
...
for name in names:
   cpy = copy.copy(name)
   def inner_func()
      print cpy
...
result_funcs[0]() # this will still print 'herp'
```

But this still prints 'herp'

It seems that python holds a pointer to the variable from the outer scope which points to the actual value
(like a pointer to a pointer)

What I ultimately want is for each inner function created to hold the value of name during the iteration it was defined in.

Can someone please explain to me where I am wrong here and how can I achieve my goal?

Thank you!

Comment: Correct your code. It's flawed.

Comment: "It seems that python holds a pointer to the variable from the outer scope which points to the actual value (like a pointer to a pointer)". Not quite. Each function stored in the list merely resolves the name `name` at runtime.

Comment: IMHO, thinking about Python's data model in terms of pointers and other terms derived from C's data model is rarely fruitful. Instead, try to embrace it in its own terms, as described in [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables) and [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: FWIW, you can easily create your function list with `[lambda n=name: print(n) for name in names]`, although in Python 2 you'll need `from __future__ import print_function` at the start of the script (before any other imports) to enable the `print` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` is evaluated lazily, as you have guessed.

You could force binding of `name` by defining `name` as the default value of an argument (that you're not using)

There are several ways to do it, one is very simple: like this:

```
  def inner_func(n=name):
     print(n)
```

now it prints `"foo"`

Comment: That's pretty hacky but it's really short and convenient